# How should I test an oscillator on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, oscillator

How does one go about testing an oscillator that is designed on a PCB? I have worked with breadboards before, but never a PCB.

On breadboards, I usually test a lead connected to an output. On a PCB there are traces. Should I include a pin on a trace for testing purposes? I want to measure the output signal of an oscillator.

Comment: Adding testpoints on PCBs is a common practice.

Comment: Also poking a scope to pad of a component. But what is it that you want to test from it and how? You say an oscillator. Is it an RC oscillator, NE555, rubidium oscillator? Or do you mean a crystal, not an oscillator?

Comment: And if you add a test point/pin for the oscillator output, add one for your ground also close by.  A 2-pin 25 mil square pin header would probably do just fine here.

Answer (score 3):

If you'll test the oscillator during the R&D stage then you can simply add test points. These could be physical components like those shown below:

[image]

<sup>[Img Src](https://uk.farnell.com/keystone/5006/test-point-pcb-through-hole/dp/2301284)</sup>

These are quite useful for attaching scope probes directly. You can also place *through-hole pads* so you can solder wires for "remote" measurement or measurement with DMM *(not for oscillator testing, but for general voltage or signal measurement)*.

---

If you want to test the oscillator output during mass production, you can place "test pads":

[image]

<sup>[ImgSrc](https://www.pcbdirectory.com/community/what-are-pcb-test-points)</sup>

These pads are, generally, meant to be used with [pogo pins attached to test jigs](https://www.javelin-tech.com/blog/2016/10/pogo-pins-3d-printed-fixtures/) such as automated test equipment:

[image]

<sup>ImgSrc: Linked article above</sup>

Note that these test pads can also be used for manual measurement i.e. it's still possible to use DMM probes or scope needles but when it comes to soldering wires, since these are standalone copper pads, they may get damaged or even get peeled off so become unusable after a few soldering and desoldering.

---

If you want to test a high frequency / RF oscillator then you should consider appropriate connectors such as 50-Ohm SMA connectors as shown below, along with consideration of trace impedance and impedance matching (you can still use solder bridges but care must be taken):

[image]

<sup>[ImgSrc](https://(https://www.digikey.at/en/product-highlight/s/samtec/sma-50-ohm-rf-connectors-and-cables))</sup>

And, of course, scope settings should be adjusted accordingly (i.e. bandwidth, termination, etc).

---

NOTE: For all the options listed above, consider the possible effects (or even possibility) of loading the oscillator with the probes. For example, if you'll probe the XTAL oscillator pins of an MCU with a scope, the probe will bring an extra load capacitance of 10-15 pF.

Comment: For high-frequency clocks where signal integrity can be an issue, you don't want the test point to be on a stub. Note that on the PWB example, the test points will have minimal effect on the signal quality.

Comment: Another important note is that directly connecting probes to the oscillator will capacitively load it, and this may disturb the signal or stop the oscillator from functioning altogether. Check what the maximum capacitive load it can handle, and consider if you need a buffer.